# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in qt C++ command line code

Tags: c++, c, qt

I am getting a segmentation fault while running a Qt-C++ program:

`dlg.h`:

```
#include<QGridLayout>
#include<QPushButton>
#include<QDialog>

class dlg : public QDialog{
        private:
                QPushButton *btn1,*btn2,*btn3,*btn4,*btn5,*btn6,*btn7,*btn8,*btn9,*btn10,*btn11,*btn12;
                QGridLayout *gridlayout;
        public:
                dlg();
};
```

`dlg.cpp`:

```
#include "dlg.h"

dlg::dlg(){
        btn1 = new QPushButton("btn1");
        btn1 = new QPushButton("btn2");
        btn1 = new QPushButton("btn3");
        btn1 = new QPushButton("btn4");
        btn1 = new QPushButton("btn5");
        btn1 = new QPushButton("btn6");
        btn1 = new QPushButton("btn7");
        btn1 = new QPushButton("btn8");
        btn1 = new QPushButton("btn9");
        btn1 = new QPushButton("btn10");
        btn1 = new QPushButton("btn11");
        btn1 = new QPushButton("btn12");

        gridlayout = new QGridLayout(this);


        gridlayout->addWidget(btn1,0,0);
        gridlayout->addWidget(btn2,0,1);
        gridlayout->addWidget(btn3,0,2);
        gridlayout->addWidget(btn4,0,3);
        gridlayout->addWidget(btn5,1,0);
        gridlayout->addWidget(btn6,1,1);
        gridlayout->addWidget(btn7,1,2);
        gridlayout->addWidget(btn8,1,3);
        gridlayout->addWidget(btn9,2,0);
        gridlayout->addWidget(btn10,2,1);
        gridlayout->addWidget(btn11,2,2);
        gridlayout->addWidget(btn12,2,3);

        setLayout(gridlayout);

        setWindowTitle("* QGridLayout  *");     
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<QApplication>
#include "dlg.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char** argv){
        QApplication app(argc,argv);
        dlg obj;
        obj.show();

        return app.exec();
}
```

I saved this all files in a directory named `gridlayout` and ran these comamnds in the terminal:

```
cd /hom/gridlayout/
qmake -project
qmake gridlayout.pro
make
```

and I am getting this error:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Is there any one who can solve this problem. I am referring  Mastering C++ Programming by Jeganathan Swaminathan [this](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-c-programming/9781786461629/) book for Qt command line C++ coding.

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: `btn1 = ...; btn1 = ...; btn1 = ...;` etc. Copy-paste error?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks .. Little frustrated by looking at screen that's why haven't seen. Big Thanks ... :)

Comment: @Omkar use the [member inizialize list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) instead of assigning variable inside the constructor body, it will help you to avoid this kinds of error other than been more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You repeatedly wrote `btn1`. You probably meant `btn1`, `btn2`, ... Consider using `std::list` (since GUI elements are probably not copyable) and loops instead of copy-pasting the same line over and over again:

```cpp
class dlg : public QDialog{
        private:
                std::list<QPushButton> buttons;
                QGridLayout gridlayout;
        public:
                dlg();
};

dlg::dlg() : gridlayout (this) {
    for (std::uint_fast8_t x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
        for (std::uint_fast8_t y = 0; y < 4; ++y) {
            gridlayout.addWidget (buttons.emplace_back ("btn" + std::to_string(x*4+y)), x, y);
        }
    }

    setLayout(gridlayout);

    setWindowTitle("* QGridLayout  *");     
}
```

This example also avoids the manual memory management.

Comment: Idea is great to use <vector> but it is giving lot of error. Maybe I have to change business logic . but thanks for your previous ans .

Comment: Yeah `std::vector` probably won't work, changed it to `std::list`.